# Force PWA notification to show only in Chrome for Mobile?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have PWA notification that asks user to "Add to homescreen". However, it shows up in Chrome for both Desktop and Mobile. I would like to show this notification only if user view my website from mobile. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this programmatically. You can listen for `beforeinstallprompt` event and only show the install prompt for whatever users you would like to target.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

Comment: This mean I need to detect the browser agent as well in order to detect if it is chrome in mobile or desktop? Am I right?